# Display text from a key/value pair in a nested dictionary

Tags: python

I'm a novice.
I am trying to print the elements from the Periodic Table to the screen arranged like the table itself. I'm using (' - ') to separate the symbols that I haven't written in the dictionary yet. I'm only using a nested dictionary with two entries total to minimize confusion.

[Training Source](http://introtopython.org/dictionaries.html) last exercise.

I asked this question elsewhere and someone (correctly) suggested using str.join(list) but It wasn't part of the tutorial. 
I'm trying to teach myself and I want to understand. No schooling, no work, no instructor.

The hints at the bottom of the linked tutorial says:

1."Use a for loop to loop through each element. Pick out the elements' row numbers and column numbers."

2."Use two nested for loops to print either an element's symbol or a series of spaces, depending on how full that row is."

I'd like to solve it this way. Thanks in advance. 
Note* No, pre-intermediate, intermediate or advanced code please, the tutorial has only covered code related to variables, strings, numbers, lists, tuples, functions(beginners),if statements, while loops, basic terminal apps and dictionaries.

Lastly I'd like to have the table itself printed with the shape of the real Periodic Table. If you could throw in a bit of that code for a novice it'd really help thanks.

My attempt(wrong):

```
ptable = {'mercury':{'symbol':'hg','atomic number': '80','row': '6','column': '12','weight':'200.59',}, 'tungsten':{'symbol':'w','atomic number':'74','row':'6','column':'6','weight':'183.84'},}

for line in range(1,7): 
    for key in ptable:
        row = int(ptable[key]['row'])
        column = int(ptable[key]['column'])
        if line != row:
                print('-'*18)
        else:
                space = 18 - column
                print('-'*(column-1)+ptable[key]['symbol']+'-'*space)
```

outputs:

```
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
-----------hg------
-----w------------
```

The output should have 7 lines as in the Periodic table. It is supposed to display the symbols of each element in the correct place as in the Periodic Table. Since I only have two elements in the library it should show Hg and W in their correct places

The experienced programmers' solution:

```
for line in range(1, 8): # line will count from 1 to 7

# display represents the line of elements we will print later

# hyphens show that the space is empty

# so we fill the list with hyphens at first

display = ['-'] * 18

for key in ptable:
    if int(ptable[key]['row']) == line:
        # if our element is on this line
        # add that element to our list
        display[int(ptable[key]['column']) - 1] = ptable[key]['symbol']

# str.join(list) will "join" the elements of your list into a new string
# the string you call it on will go in between all of your elements
print(''.join(display))
```

Comment: What does your output look like? What does correct output look like?

Comment: My output looks like this. ------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
------------------
-----------hg------
-----w------------ . The output is supposed to display the symbols of each element in the correct place as in the Periodic Table and. Since I only have two elements in the library it should show. Hg and W in their correct places.

Comment: Can you include that in your question and format it as code, so that all the line breaks show up?

Answer (score 0):

I honestly think this code isn't that hard to understand and I think trying to change it would only make it more complicated. I'm going to put you some links at the end for you to check it out and understand the ''join() method and the range() function which you seem not to understand either. You said you wanted to learn Python by yourself and that's a great thing! (I'm doing it too) But that doesn't mean you have to stick to a tutorial ;). You can go beyond it and also skip the parts you don't care about and come back later when you need them. If you need explanations about methods (like ''.join) or any other thing let me know. Sorry if that doesn't help you ;(.

Links:

[The .join() method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm)

[The range() function](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pythons-range-function-explained/)

Comment: I understand the code suggested. I wanted to do it like the tutorial suggested. I suspect whoever designed the tutorial intended for the learner to develop problem solving skills with the limited topics covered up till then. Given that it was a bonus exercise, I'm not miffed I couldn't solve it, but I would like to know what the designer had in mind.